# Create DynamoDB table in serverless yml file

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, yaml

I am going to create the table in yml file. When I write as below, at first it is created successfully.

```
  UsersTable:
  Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
  Properties:
    TableName: users
    AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: user_id
        AttributeType: S
    KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: user_id
        KeyType: HASH
    ProvisionedThroughput:
      ReadCapacityUnits: 5
      WriteCapacityUnits: 5
```

But I need more attributes, so I changed like belows.

```
  UsersTable:
  Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
  Properties:
    TableName: users
    AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: user_id
        AttributeType: S
      - AttributeName: email_lower_case
        AttributeType: S
      - AttributeName: book_id
        AttributeType: S
      - AttributeName: book_amount
        AttributeType: S  
    KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: user_id
        KeyType: HASH
    ProvisionedThroughput:
      ReadCapacityUnits: 5
      WriteCapacityUnits: 5
```

But it shows error like this.

```
An error occurred: UsersTable - One or more parameter values were invalid: Number of attributes in KeySchema does not exactly match number of attributes defined in AttributeDefinitions
```

I don't want to use other KeySchema. Is it possible to create such a table?
Can't I create the table with attributes that are not included in any index?

Comment: You don't have define any attribute other than hash and range key. Your program can create as many attributes you want during the insert or update.

Answer (score 2):

You must include keys in the attribute definitions.

```
  UsersTable:
  Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
  Properties:
    TableName: users
    AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: user_id
        AttributeType: S

      - AttributeName: bitwage_user_id
        AttributeType: S
      - AttributeName: email_lower_case
        AttributeType: S
      - AttributeName: book_id
        AttributeType: S
      - AttributeName: book_amount
        AttributeType: S  
    KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: user_id
        KeyType: HASH
    ProvisionedThroughput:
      ReadCapacityUnits: 5
      WriteCapacityUnits: 5
```